# Counting change in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming

I came across the following solution to the DP problem of [counting change](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change):

```
count' :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
count' cents coins = aux coins !! cents
  where aux = foldr addCoin (1:repeat 0)
          where addCoin c oldlist = newlist
                  where newlist = (take c oldlist) ++ zipWith (+) newlist (drop c oldlist)
```

It ran much faster than my naive top-down recursive solution, and I'm still trying to understand it.

I get that given a list of coins, `aux` computes every solution for the positive integers. Thus the solution for an amount is to index the list at that position.

I'm less clear on `addCoin`, though. It somehow uses the value of each coin to draw elements from the list of coins? I'm struggling to find an intuitive meaning for it.

The fold in `aux` also ties my brain up in knots. Why is `1:repeat 0` the initial value? What does it represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a direct translation of the imperative DP algorithm for the problem, which looks like this (in Python):

```py
def count(cents, coins):
    solutions = [1] + [0]*cents # [1, 0, 0, 0, ... 0]
    for coin in coins:
        for i in range(coin, cents + 1):
            solutions[i] += solutions[i - coin]
    return solutions[cents]
```

In particular, `addCoin coin solutions` corresponds to

```
for i in range(coin, cents + 1):
    solutions[i] += solutions[i - coin]
```

except that `addCoin` returns a modified list instead of mutating the old one. As to the Haskell version, the result should have an unchanged section at the beginning until the `coin`-th element, and after that we must implement `solutions[i] += solutions[i - coin]`.

We realize the unchanged part by `take c oldlist` and the modified part by `zipWith (+) newlist (drop c oldlist)`. In the modified part we add together the `i`-th elements of the old list and `i - coin`-th elements of the resulting list. The shifting of indices is implicit in the `drop` and `take` operations.

A simpler, classic example for this kind of shifting and recursive definition is the Fibonacci numbers:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

We would write this imperatively as

```
def fibs(limit):
    res = [0, 1] + [0]*(limit - 2)
    for i in range(2, limit):
        res[i] = res[i - 2] + res[i - 1]
    return res
```

Turning back to coin change, `foldr addCoin (1:repeat 0)` corresponds to the initialization of `solutions` and the for loop on the coins, with the change that the initial list is infinite instead of finite (because laziness lets us do that).